# PendingIntent to finish current 3rd party activity as well as starting it's corresponding activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, android-task

My app passes a PendingIntent (which calls my own Activity) to a 3rd party app as well as starting an Activity in that 3rd party app.

At some point, the 3rd party app starts that PendingIntent (on some button click), but it does not finish its own Activity.

I'm wondering if there is a way (perhaps using Intent flags, or TaskStackBuilder) to construct the PendingIntent in such a way that the 3rd party Activity will be automatically finished?

Comment: What's your objective? So pressing BACK from the activity identified as "my own Activity" returns to whatever started all this off in the first place, bypassing the third-party app's intervening activity?

Comment: Correct. Actually, in this example there is only one relevant activity in my app. That activity starts the 3rd party activity and then is "started" by the 3rd party activity using the pending intent. My objective is to avoid a long back stack of the 3rd party activities. I actually now have a solution (which I will post below) but it feels like a bit of a hack.

Comment: Think of my activity as a list where clicking on each item launches the 3rd party activity. And the 3rd party activity can bring up the list (my activity) via the pending intent.

Answer (score 2):

Use launchMode `singleTask` for the activity in your app. This will mean the 3rd party app activity will be finished as soon as it triggers the Pending Intent.

Comment: Putting `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`, or possibly `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED`, in the `Intent` wrapped in the `PendingIntent` should have the same effect, with the bonus of having finer granularity, in case there are situations where you cannot support `singleTask` behavior for this activity.

Comment: Thanks and normally this would work, but in this particular case (sorry, probably some critical info missing from question) it does not. I suspect, the 3rd party app is starting its own task (I think it's using `taskAffinity`; cannot be `launchMode` because, if it was, activities would not stack up).  By specifying `launchMode` in manifest (`singleTask`), I can force the 3rd party activities to close (or maybe shift to some other "hidden" task). I can't find a way to do all this with `Intent` flags, although I agree that would be better.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably stuck with this solution then.

Comment: Be aware that using android:launchMode="singleTask" will lead to android task hijacking